# ASP.NET MVC intermittent 401 authorization errors

Tags: asp.net, iis, kerberos

I have an ASP.NET MVC intranet site that uses Windows Authentication (Kerberos) exclusively with pass-through authentication. It is setup to use an app pool (v4/integrated) that uses the Network Service identity.  The web site provides a pretty UI on top of a network share that is hosted on another machine (SAMBA NAS box).  Occassionally (and usually when someone hasn't accessed the site for a while), clients are getting a 401 authorization error at the point the MVC code is trying to get directory info (System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime) on the remote UNC share.  The event log on the IIS machine captures a security audit failure at this same point in time:

```
+ System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 
   [ Guid]  {54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d} 

   EventID 4625 

   Version 0 

   Level 0 

   Task 12544 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x8010000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2012-03-17T00:43:50.522Z 

   EventRecordID 398873 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  696 
   [ ThreadID]  792 

   Channel Security 

   Computer lvtloweb1.acme.com 

   Security 


- EventData 

  SubjectUserSid S-1-0-0 
  SubjectUserName - 
  SubjectDomainName - 
  SubjectLogonId 0x0 
  TargetUserSid S-1-0-0 
  TargetUserName  
  TargetDomainName  
  Status 0xc000006d 
  FailureReason %%2304 
  SubStatus 0xc0000133 
  LogonType 3 
  LogonProcessName Kerberos 
  AuthenticationPackageName Kerberos 
  WorkstationName - 
  TransmittedServices - 
  LmPackageName - 
  KeyLength 0 
  ProcessId 0x0 
  ProcessName - 
  IpAddress - 
  IpPort -
```

The weird thing is that if you sit and refresh the page over and over, it usually get's past the 401 error in about a minute.  Anybody got any ideas on how to troubleshoot such a problem?  Oh yeah, the IIS machine is hosted in a VM.  The guest OS is Windows Server 2008 Enterprise 6.0.6002 Service Pack 2.

Comment: Is IIS doing the actual authentication or your MVC app? I ran into a similar problem having left "Integrated Windows authentication" checked in IIS while using MADAM for auth.

Comment: Yes, Integrated Windows Auth is enabled on the IIS site.  What is MADAM?

Comment: Sort of an authentication mechanism juggling library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479391.aspx#madam_topic5 In my case I had just failed to follow the configuration instructions fully :/

Comment: It's probably not related, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the pass-through authentication you refer to ? Is it Kerberos delegation or microsoft S4U extensions ? Do you maintain a user's TGT in a cache in IIS ?

Comment: @YvesMartin I'm pretty sure it's Kerberos.  If caching the user's TGT requires extra setup then we are not doing that. I'll need to look when I get back into work on Monday to verify this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keith,

Being that it appears to happen most after the user has been idle, I'm leaning towards some kind event (i.e. a session timeout) that might invalidate the credentials for your server. I'm assuming one server since you didn't mention any web farm.

A part of me thinks you've likely hammered the session timeout angle. Unless you felt safe trusting that the users would 'auto authenticate' and timing out mid operation wouldn't cause it to fail. That said, I'm not sure I'd completely trust that is the case. To at least eliminate this possibility I would add a routine that logs information about the current session/credentials before that operation is started. Even though the user is "always logged in" assuming they are on their computer I've seen weird issues with VPNs, proxy servers, server double hops, IE configurations for 'trusted zones' and 'intranet' settings. Even a computer suddenly having its route to the server changed could cause issues. I'm not sure the network emulation on a VM would play a part, but who knows.

Here is a 'starter' article regarding IE and it's complex approach to authentication and the role it plays as the client application accessing your Intranet MVC app. (It pays to dig deep on how IE auto-magically authenticates in a Windows AD environment.)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063/en-us

Here is a related problem someone had due to a double-hop causing 401s. I've also included a link to another good 'starter page' on investigating these types of issues.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/6d1604e5-e739-41e4-89a5-c6681bff2e61

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx

Sorry if anything above you already knew or for the general nature of my response. It's tough without actually having network access or being able to add logging to your code. I hope I've pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome, should you get more information based no some of those tests I'd be curious to hear more to dial in the troubleshooting direction.